# In BASH, how do you reference a directory name in a copy statement of files you recursively "find"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, command-line-arguments

1. I want to recursively find all files that end with *DETAIL.pdf
2. Create a new directory (in another drive) for each file with the same name as the original directory
3. Copy the file into the new directory

I have this as my current attempt:
`find . -name \*DETAIL.pdf -type f -not -path "./test2" -exec cp -R {} ./test2 \;`

I am struggling to create new directories for all these files by referencing the original directory name of each file.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions for guidance on how to pass the names identified by `find` into a shell so you can perform [parameter expansions](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) on them (f/e, `${var%/*}` to trim off the filename and leave only the directory efficiently).

Comment: BTW, step (2) is somewhat underspecified. (Create a new directory with the original directory's name, _where_? If it were created in the same place as the original directory, it might as well just _be_ the original directory, unless you want the code to move the original directory out of the way, but it doesn't say anything about that; etc).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with one pdf file as example with its full path and the new directory with its full path.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Ah. Sorry about that. I want to move it to another drive (source is remote, destination is local)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example mentions using `cp` but the question/problem itself does not, so I would suggest just using `find` and `tar`. Also, though the question is a little ambiguous as noted in the comments above, the example seems to suggest that the desired output directory is a child of the same directory being searched. Given that:

```
find . -path "./test2" -prune -o -type f -name '*DETAIL.pdf' -print0 | \
tar c --null --files-from=- | \
tar xC test2
```

This uses `find` for file selection, generating a (null-separated) file list, which `tar` then uses to copy the files, and the second `tar` will create the relative directories as needed and write the copied files.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Can you explain the "-print0" portion?

Comment: `-print0` and `--null` are counterparts that use NUL bytes instead of line feeds to separate the filenames. This prevents any unusual characters in filenames from confusing the file list.

Comment: FYI.  This answer does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  You mention above that I was using 'cp' but the question does not.  'cp' COPIES the files to the new location.  This is what I intended to do, as stated in step #3.  Just want to be on the same page with you.

Comment: The switch to `tar` helps because it allows you to copy files with a directory structure intact. FWIW the `-0` etc are GNU-specific, so not portable to POSIX generally (though usually fine on Linux and many other platforms).

Comment: `tar c` creates an archive (reads the files) and then `tar x` immediately extracts it (with `C dirname` changing to that directory first) to write the files to the new directory -- so it does copy them

Comment: It sounds like you might have a filesystem or device error, which is outside the scope of the OP. I would see if you can `ls B`, and look for errors in the system log.